# Version Saving my Excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a little script that will save the file I'm working on, and when doing so increment the version number on it. I've got a script that works fine when I call it from a normal `Sub` but as soon as I put it in the `BeforeSave` Event the whole application crashes.

I've placed this in the `ThisWorkbook` Object of the workbook that I want to version.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim fso
    Dim nme As String, rootDir As String
    Dim ver As Integer

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    With ThisWorkbook
        nme = fso.GetBaseName(.Name)
        rootDir = fso.getfolder(.Path)
        On Error Resume Next
        ver = CInt(Trim(Right(nme, Len(nme) - InStr(1, nme, " v", vbTextCompare) - 1))) + 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        nme = "GNOC into CPT DE" ' Trim(Left(nme, InStr(1, nme, " v", vbTextCompare)))

        .SaveAs Filename:=rootDir & "\" & nme & " v" & Format(ver, "000"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably because you're saving twice? Why can't you just do a `wb.saveas filename:= blah blah` in a sub?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to enter an infinite loop with your current setup (before the user initiated save, the macro causes a SaveAs to update the version, but that again invokes the `BeforeSave` event, re-invoking the macro, and so on).

To get around this you need a blocking variable. In the `ThisWorkbook` object create a variable, for the sake of convenience I'll call it `Block`, as a Boolean. With the `Open` event set Block to False. Add the following between your declarations & you `Set`:

```
If Not Block Then
    Block = True
```

Indent the whole of code except the `End Sub`. Between the `End With` & `End Sub` insert:

```
    Block = False
End If 'No Else case needed as nothing special should happen if block is true
```

That should be it.

Comment: Ok so you're using a global variable to switch it on and off? Is there no way of interrupting the initial save that triggers the event?

Comment: Yup, nothing pretty, but it's simple and effective. The only way I know of to interrupt a user initiate save is the `BeforeSave` event.

Comment: After you mentioning the recursion I thought about it a bit more and came up with a solution. I've cancelled the save, and then disable events so that I can save. This way I avoid using a global variable and can use the same code over and over instead of only once before having to close and open the file again. Thanks for your input

Comment: With the `Block = False` at the end of the `If` statement you wouldn't need to close & re-open to have the versioning work. After each successful save (including the renaming) Block gets reset to False, so that the next Save works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this a bit longer and came up with the following which works perfectly

Using `Cancel = True` I cancel the save that has been initiated by the user and then by disabling events I can save without re-triggering this event. And then I have versioning for my Excel dev work

---

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim fso
    Dim nme As String, rootDir As String
    Dim ver As Integer

    Cancel = True

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    With ThisWorkbook
        nme = fso.GetBaseName(.Name)
        rootDir = fso.getfolder(.Path)
        On Error Resume Next
        ver = CInt(Trim(Right(nme, Len(nme) - InStr(1, nme, " v", vbTextCompare) - 1))) + 1
        On Error GoTo 0
        nme = Trim(Left(nme, InStr(1, nme, " v", vbTextCompare)))
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .SaveAs Filename:=rootDir & "\" & nme & " v" & Format(ver, "000"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```